# Spring Security - antMatchers path pattern does not behave as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, postman

I have created a project with Spring Security and JWT Tokens. 
 
I observed that the path specified in `configure` method in `WebSecurityConfig` class does not behave equally for different HTTP methods. 
 
My `ConcertRESTController` that I am trying to secure looks as following:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/concerts")
public class ConcertRESTController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<Concert> getAllConcerts() {
        // get all concerts logic
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Concert> addConcert(@RequestBody Concert concert) {
        // add concert logic
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteConcertById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        // delete concert logic
    }
```

And `WebSecurityConfig`:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/concerts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/concerts/**").hasRole("admin")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/concerts/**").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore((Filter) authenticationJwtTokenFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

However, the only method that works with this pattern is `HttpMethod.GET`. Other two give me status 403 when trying to call them with admin rights in Postman.

```
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Forbidden",
"path": "/concerts"
```

What is interesting, when I change them to:

```java
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/concerts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "concerts/**").hasRole("admin")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "concerts/**").hasRole("admin")
```

All works as expected. 
Could anyone explain this behaviour? Thank you in advance!

---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Edit - adding code for `JwtAuthTokenFilter` class

```java
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String jwt = getJwt(httpServletRequest);
            if (jwt != null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

In `WebSecurityConfig`:

```java
@Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }
```

Comment: that is indeed strange. can you try using mvcmatchers instead of antmatchers

Comment: @pvpkiran Thank you for the reply. I have tried using mvcmatchers - still getting 403 though.

Comment: Please add the code for `authenticationJwtTokenFilter`

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva I have just added the code of class `JwtAuthTokenFilter`

Comment: can you try two things ? 1) call you POST request with permit all 2) switch the sequence of GET and POST requests. let me know what you see ?

Comment: Try setting `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`  and see the output. Our put it here.

Comment: Maybe ` hasRole("admin")` is looking for a ROLE_admin and you role database has olny admin in it.

Comment: @YogendraR Both POST and DELETE work with `permitAll()`. Swtitching the sequence of `antMatchers` however does not solve the issue.

Comment: ```org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
 at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core```
```at com.jlewand.demo.security.jwt.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:45) [classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no issue with your end points. The problem is with your role.

`hasRole` automatically inserts "ROLE_" in the parameters.

You need to make sure few things:

1) If your role is stored as "ROLE_admin", then use `hasRole("admin")`.

2) If your role is stored as "admin", then you should use `hasAuthority("admin")`.

> What is interesting, when I change them to:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/concerts/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "concerts/**").hasRole("admin")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "concerts/**").hasRole("admin")
```

In above case `FilterSecurityInterceptor` does not consider your end point as Secure object instead it consider it as Public object, so make sure your pattern starts with forward slash. You can see below logs:

```
2020-06-06 17:22:56 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/concerts'; against 'concerts/**'
2020-06-06 17:22:56 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:210 - Public object - authentication not attempted

2020-06-06 17:44:23 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:176 - Checking match of request : '/concerts'; against '/concerts/**'
2020-06-06 17:44:23 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:219 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /concerts; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_Admin')]
```

Comment: That's it! I am storing the roles in database as `ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN`.
I have changed ```antMatchers()``` from ```.hasRole("admin")``` to ```.hasRole("ADMIN")``` and it works! I didn't even suppose it might be case-sensitive. Thank you so much!